# Is it possible to retrain once trained tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I trained faster RCNN tensorflow object detection API to train on my data on google colab. After 10 hours of training I saved model on google drive. But when I checked inference on test images result wasn't satisfactory. So I want to continue training of model from where I saved model.

1. Is it possible to use latest checkpoints for further training.
2. If yes how we can do that?

Any kind of help would appreciated.

Comment: check this link : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to continue training the model.

here is an example of how you can save and load checkpoints to continue training.

`ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=opt, net=net, iterator=iterator)`

`manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, './tf_ckpts', max_to_keep=3)`

Where net is keras model /tf module.

you load the latest checkpoint from "./tf_ckpts" folder like so

```
   def restore_checkpoint(manager):
      ckpt.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
      if manager.latest_checkpoint:
        print("Restored from {}".format(manager.latest_checkpoint))
      else:
        print("Initializing from scratch.")
```